# Executar script PHP no agendador de tarefas do Windows

Tags: php, agendamento

Tenho um script PHP que atualmente deixo rodando com um navegador aberto, com o comando abaixo:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="1800">
```

Apesar dos problemas de mémoria que o navegador consome, estava rodando tudo tranquilamente. Agora preciso desenvolver mais 3 scripts que também irão rodar de tempos em tempos.
 
Existe alguma forma de executar o script via gerenciador de tarefas? 
Fiz um teste com prompt, mas não obtive sucesso, pois independentemente do script, ele retorna sempre um parse error que não existe.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\wamp\www\reservas\Enviar
EmailLembrete.php on line 281

C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12>php c:\wamp\www\reservas\EnviarEmailLembrete.php
```

Alterando para localhost:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12>php -f http://localhost/reservas/EnviarEmailLembrete.p
hp
Could not open input file: http://localhost/reservas/EnviarEmailLembrete.php
```

Código [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqnw4fe1/)

Comment: Só colocar `php -f "c:\wamp\www\reservas\EnviarEmail.php"` no prompt não funciona?

Comment: Não, ele dá o erro que coloquei na pergunta, em qualquer script que executo...

Comment: O que tem nessa linha? talvez tenha algum caracter invisivel. Se tiver o notepad++ abra o arquivo vá no menu `view>show symblos>show all symbols.`

Comment: Com o textpad ele só mostra espaços em branco, nao tem nada nessa linha...

Comment: Removendo os espaço da um resultado diferente?

Comment: Não querendo ser chato :D, poderia fazer mais dois testes, talvez vc tenha um problema de ambiente. 1 - crie um script simples um `echo 'ola '. mt_rand(1,10000)` e roda-lo via prompt e ver  se acontece o mesmo erro. 2 - Se possível tente executar o script original em outra instalação do php. Digo isso pq outro vi uma pergunta de usuário q não conseguia instalar um lib(intl) tinha feito o processo correto e não ia de jeito nenhum, dai sugeri q ele trocasseo wamp pelo xampp e funcionou. O wamp e easyPHP parecem ser meio zicados ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solução mais usual é agendar desta forma:

```
c:/caminhocorreto/php -c c:/caminho/para/o/php.ini [ -f ] c:/caminho/para/o/script.php
```

Desta forma, você estará pegando o executável certo e o `php.ini` correto para o que deseja fazer.

> Documentação dos parâmetros de inicialização do PHP:
>   http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.commandline.options.php

O único cuidado é entender que como não está usando o servidor web (Apache, etc), não funcionarão definições que estão em arquivos `.htaccess` e outras coisas típicas do *webserver*, como as variáveis `$_SERVER[]`.

Uma alternativa se a tarefa for mais recorrente é chamar um PHP com um loop infinito no boot do sistema (com a mesma sintaxe acima), mas para não "sufocar" a CPU desnecessariamente, ao fim de cada ciclo você chama o `sleep`, que além de dar a pausa necessária entre uma execução e outra, libera a CPU para outras tarefas.

Comment: ´+1´ agora sim uma resposta bonita :)

Answer (score 6):

O problema existe sim, é que no apache a sua configuração deve estar de uma maneira e no momento que executa diretamente `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12>php` ele deve estar usando outra configuração do *php.ini*, no caso você esta usando blocos assim:

```
<?

?>
```

Mas dependendo das configurações do php.ini precisará usar assim:

```
<?php

?>
```

O seu script falhou porque o php.ini que esta com o `short_open_tag` desativado, o php.ini que o apache usa é diferente as vezes, geralmente alguns servidores fazem isto pois que roda por **linha de comando** precisa de extensões e configurações diferentes da camada HTTP, recomendo que sempre use `<?php`, pra evitar dores de cabeça, já que ele funcionará em todos servidores, diferente do `short_open_tag` que só funciona se habilitado.

> Uma nota, pode usar `<?="oi" ?>` mesmo com `short_open_tag` desativadas, isto funciona no *PHP5.4+* normalmente, equivalente ao `<?php echo "oi"; ?>`.

E execute depois via linha de comando, executei no terminal e funcionou:

[image: CLI]

Depois é só colocar no agendador de tarefas do Windows.

- Digite no cmd `taskschd.msc` e clique em tarefa básica:

  [image: task]
- Digite e titulo e em proximo:

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- Selecione diariamente:

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- Agende pra quando quer iniciar e o numero de dias de intervalo (se quiser diariamente deixe 1):

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- Selecione iniciar programa:

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- Adicione o programa php e no argumentos adicione o caminho do script php:

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- Clique em concluir.