# Como rodar um código sem página aberta no PHP

Tags: php, windows

Eu possuo um código PHP que usa o `FSOCKOPEN` para checar a porta de um servidor, e dependendo da resposta ele registra em log... Mas para isso a página tem que sempre ficar aberta, eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de eu deixar isso rodando automático no servidor sem interface com usuário...

Hoje para ele funcionar eu deixo uma tag HTML atualizando a página a cada 10 segundos... Mas como disse, para rodar a pagina tem sempre que ficar aberta!

Comment: Acho q vc tem q usar crontab, com isso vc agenda os horários pra rodar seu script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caros amigos, consegui resolver o problema seguindo o passo a passo descrito no artigo a seguir:
Fonte: [Executar script PHP no agendador de tarefas do Windows](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129554/executar-script-php-no-agendador-de-tarefas-do-windows)

- Digite no cmd `taskschd.msc` e clique em tarefa básica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Digite e titulo e em proximo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Selecione diariamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Agende pra quando quer iniciar e o numero de dias de intervalo (se
  quiser diariamente deixe 1):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Selecione iniciar programa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Adicione o programa php e no argumentos adicione o caminho do script
  php:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Clique em concluir.

Answer (score 3):

Se estiver utilizando **Linux**, pode ser usando o [**crontab**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab):

```
*/12 * * * *  /usr/bin/php -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /var/www/html/seu_php.php
```

Onde:

- 12 = 60 segundos / 5 segundos (a cada 5 segundos)
- /usr/bin/php = caminho do seu executável do PHP
- /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini = caminho do seu arquivo php.ini (configuração do PHP)
- /var/www/html/seu_php.php = Caminho completo do script PHP que você deseja executar

Caso esteja utilizando **Windows**, coloque no agendador de tarefas:

```
c:\WAMP\php\bin\php.exe -c c:\WAMP\php\php.ini c:\WAMP\www\seu_php.php
```

Onde:

- c:\WAMP\php\bin\php.exe = caminho do seu executável do PHP
- c:\WAMP\php\php.ini = caminho do seu arquivo php.ini (configuração do PHP)
- c:\WAMP\www\seu_php.php = Caminho completo do script PHP que você deseja executar

Comment: Então, estou utilizando XAMP no Windows! :(

Faria isso pelo Agendado de Tarefas do Windows tb?

Comment: Sim, atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Não sei se vem ao caso, qualquer coisa apago o comentário.. Mas se uso um servidor compartilhado e não tenho acesso à esses recursos, teria alguma outra solução? Posso precisar disso no futuro

Comment: @Murilo, sem página aberta, acredito que utilizando outro servidor (com estes recursos) para fazer uma requisição HTTP a cada 5 segundos. Não conheço outra forma... mas não excluo a possibilidade de que possa existir alguma solução melhor.

Comment: Olha, eu não consegui fazer colocando esse código no agendador de tarefas do Windows, ele até roda a janela, mas não executa o código de forma correta, contornando eu estou deixando uma janela aberta e minimizada la no cantão e trabalhando normalmente... :(

Comment: Você rodou o comando no MS-DOS (terminal do windows), antes de colocar ele no agendador de tarefas, para testar?