# Agendamento de script PHP em Windows

Tags: php, windows, xampp

Tenho uma VM de ambiente teste com `Windows Server` + `Xampp`.

Preciso disparar um arquivo (`script.php`) com agendamento de 5 em 5 minutos.

**Qual a forma mais simples e ágil ?**

> Update 1

Pelo "Agendador de Tarefas" do Windows, o menor intervalo é "diário":

[image: Agendador de Tarefas]

Comment: Agendador de tarefas do windows

Comment: Coloco para executar o arquivo `php` ?

Comment: pode executar o php tipo php arquivo.php ou url direta do arquivo

Comment: Só tem "diariamente". Com intervalo em minutos não !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249542/run-a-task-every-x-minutes-with-windows-task-scheduler

Comment: Em `uma vez` ele não abre o valor do intervalo?

Comment: @rray não, ele abre uma data e horário somente.

Comment: @Otto é isso aí ! Quer postar a resposta ? Se não eu faço os prints e posto... vou testar se vai funcionar a execução...

Comment: Não funcionou. Eu colocar para executar o arquivo em .php, não seria mesma coisa que clicar nele para abrir ? Dessa forma ele não tem um programa padrão...

Comment: Fiz uma edição na resposta colocando como fazer para rodar o scripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tarefa deve ser configurada em dois passos.

Primeiro você deve criar uma tarefa simples iniciando as 0:00, todos os dias. Após isto, você vai em `Avançado` (ou algo similar dependendo da versão do SO) e seleciona `Repetir a cada X minutos` por 24 horas.

A chave aqui é encontrar as propriedades avançadas. Se você estiver usando o assistente do XP, ele só oferecerá o início da caixa de diálogo avançada depois que você criar a tarefa.

Em versões mais recentes do Windows (7+):

1. Clique duas vezes na tarefa e uma janela de propriedades será exibida.
2. Clique na guia `Triggers`.
3. Clique duas vezes nos detalhes do gatilho e a janela do Trigger de Edição será exibida.
4. No painel `Configurações avançadas`, assinale `Repetir tarefa a cada` xxx minutos e defina `Indefinidamente` se necessitar.
5. Finalmente, clique em ok.

Aproveitando segue tambem como executar um php via scheduler:

C:\Path\to\php.exe -f "C:\Path\to\file.php"

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249542/run-a-task-every-x-minutes-with-windows-task-scheduler)

Comment: Deu certo. Olha a resposta do Guilherme Nascimento: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129554/executar-script-php-no-agendador-de-tarefas-do-windows. Obrigado ;]

Comment: Sim tem varias formas de fazer hehehe

Comment: Não, é igual a sua. Só que tem a imagem que exemplifica mais facilmente. No seu caso, seria o campo "Programa/script" = `C:\xampp\php\php.exe` e em "Adicione argumentos (opcional)" = `C:\xampp\htdocs\site\script.php`... Ou seja, ele executa o php.exe, e o argumento que seria o script, e não ao contrário. rs

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta do Otto, e desse [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129554/executar-script-php-no-agendador-de-tarefas-do-windows)

Como ficou com o `XAMPP`:

[image: ação]

Deve-se executar o `php.exe`, neste caso puxei do `XAMPP`, e o argumento seria o `caminho/script.php` do arquivo.