# Executar script PHP minimizado ou oculto, pelo Agendador de Tarefas

Tags: php, windows

Tenho uma **tarefa agendada no windows** (*funcionando perfeitamente*), onde executa um script PHP:

**Agendador**:

[image: tarefa]

**email.php**:

```
<?php
require_once 'classes/core.class.php';

set_time_limit(120);

$tempo1 = microtime(true);
$core = new Email();
$core -> enviaEmails();
$tempo2 = microtime(true);

echo '<br> tempo: ' . $tempo2 - $tempo1;
?>
```

---

O problema é, que todo o tempo aparece a janela do `cmd`, executa o script, finaliza e fecha. Como essa tarefa é executada várias vezes em um curto período, fica atrapalhando quando se trabalha em outras ferramentas.

Gostaria de saber, como faço para "ocultar" essa janela, ou ao menos iniciá-la minimizada?

Comment: Qual usuário está utilizando para executar o script?

Comment: @GabrielHeming O adm da máquina mesmo.

Comment: Mude para o usário System ou Sistema.

Comment: @GabrielHeming perfeito! Monta a resposta para eu marcar como resolvido. Vou também adicionar uma imagem nela. Obrigado!

Comment: só marcar "executar estando usuário conectado ou não"

Comment: @RovannLinhalis também funcionou cara! Só fiquei com dúvida quanto ao flag "Não armazenar a senha. A tarefa terá acesso somente aos recursos do computador local." Isso seria para evitar alterar a senha do usuário, e parar o agendamento?

Comment: Entre outras coisas... Sobre a pergunta, acho que não tem nada a ver com o php... Mas como uma funcionalidade do Windows... Tem que remover a tag ali... Talvez até fechar como fora de escopo

Comment: Ela surgiu dessa: [Agendamento de script PHP em Windows](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/287125/agendamento-de-script-php-em-windows), mas tranquilo! Por mim pode fechar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme informado no [seguinte tópico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568736/how-do-i-set-a-windows-scheduled-task-to-run-in-the-background), basta utilizar o usuário de execução como `SYSTEM` ou `SISTEMA` (dependendo do idioma do sistema operacional).

[image: tarefa]

Outra solução, apresentada no tópico acima linkado e, também, pelo comentário do [@Rovann Linhalis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/313819/executar-script-php-minimizado-ou-oculto-pelo-agendador-de-tarefas?noredirect=1#comment637263_313819), é marcar a opção "executar estando usuário conectado ou não" (*Run whether user is logged on or not*).