# Executar .BAT em segundo plano ao iniciar Windows

Tags: windows, script

Como posso rodar esse script BAT em segundo plano ou invisível ou sem janela? Adicionei o `.bat` em `Startup`, ele mostra o terminal em execução, mas não quero mostrar janela alguma, já usei ferramenta de conversão de `.bat` para `.exe`com opção de inivisível mas não funcionou.

```
cd c:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\simrede

c:\xampp\php\php.exe -S localhost:8000
```

Comment: É um script para rodar pelo agendamento, por onde?

Comment: @rbz quero que ele inicie junto com o sistema, ele já inicia, mas não quero que seja visualizada janela executando, entende?

Comment: Ele inicia junto do sistema como? Onde? Detalhe ao máximo, pois a forma que chama seu .bat é fundamental para saber!

Comment: @rbz Coloquei ele na pasta `Startup`, assim quando faço login ele inicia, mas fica mostrando a janela do terminal, e não quero que seja mostrada janela

Comment: START /B linha_de_comando.bat

Comment: @DanielOmine, não funcionou

Comment: Dependendo dos recursos e ambiente, uma solução pode ou não funcionar. Como são muitas variantes, procure esses termos "run bat file in background" no google.

Comment: Fico me perguntando o que leva um ser a negativar uma pergunta clara como essa

Comment: Dê uma olhada aqui https://www.thewindowsclub.com/run-batch-files-silently-on-windows

Comment: Olá @LeandroAngelo já resolvi, minha resposta está abaixo. Obrigado

Comment: Então marque-a como tal... para não deixar essa pergunta aberta

Comment: Só posso marcar minha própria resposta após dois dias de publicada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para o meu caso fiz o seguinte:
Criei um script em `.vbs` com o seguinte conteúdo e adiciono em Startup para iniciar no logon:

```
set objSh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objSh.Run "cmd /k c:\xampp\htdocs\simrede\inicia-PHP-xampp.bat", 0
```

Criei outro script com os comandos que desejo que sejam executados, e salvando  com nome `inicia-PHP-xampp.bat`, na pasta c:\xampp\htdocs\simrede\

Assim o script `inicia-PHP-xampp.bat` inicia em segundo plano.

Answer (score 3):

No meu caso, eu uso um script disparando-o por período, e então executo com outro usuário: [Executar script PHP minimizado ou oculto, pelo Agendador de Tarefas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/313819/executar-script-php-minimizado-ou-oculto-pelo-agendador-de-tarefas)

Você pode fazer dessa forma que fiz, e usar a opção "Ao fazer logon" para disparar:

[image: logon]

Comment: Esta opção não serve pois o usuário teria que configurar em sua máquina, como é para implementar em um instalador não é interessante

Comment: Achei que fosse algo para server, então dei a alternativa mais prática. Mas neste caso, a melhor forma mesmo seria converter, como na resposta do Laércio.

Answer (score -2):

Isso não é possível sem outros recursos como o VBS que você contornou, a menos que você volte no tempo aquém do Windows XP, quando os SOs da Microsoft eram apenas uma interface rodando no MSDOS.

Mas tem coisas que você pode fazer para minimizar esse efeito:

```
CMD /C "MODE con cols=14 lines=1 & @SeusComandosAqui"
```

Esse código executa um comando no MSDOS e fecha logo que acaba, também reduz ao máximo o tamanho da janela. Você copia esse código e cria um novo atalho com ele, a seguir marque no atalho para iniciar MINIMIZADO.
Agora ele:

- inicia minimizado,
- com janela mínima e
- encerra logo que executa.

Agora você pode colocar esse atalho na pasta <kbd>INICIALIZAR</kbd> do <kbd>**menu iniciar**</kbd>, e toda a vez que você logar, ele vai rodar.
Ou então você pode criar uma tarefa agendada:

- Windows - `%windir%\system32\taskschd.msc /s`
- Prompt - `schtasks /create /?` - veja as opções de onlogon/onstart.
  Talvez o parâmetro `onstart` até mesmo execute antes de carregar a tela de logon igual faz `CHKDSK` que checa a integridade do disco.

Mas de qualquer forma, pra que precisa(va) de um batch-script pra isso? Basta criar um atalho com os parâmetros desejados para iniciar seu servidor